# Error while storing artifacts to Nexus through Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I was trying to store artifacts to Nexus. 
When trying using the Command line using `mvn clean package deploy` the Build Sucess and Artifacts are stored in the desired Nexus repository.

Now trying the same code With Jenkins with Goals and Option `clean package deploy` till `package` it is done successfully and after that, it shows error

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ maven-webapp ---
[INFO] Downloading from deployment: http://localhost:8081/repository/sample-snap/com/infy/demos/maven-webapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.infy.demos:maven-webapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to deployment (http://localhost:8081/repository/sample-snap/): Not authorized
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.173 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-25T12:22:12+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project maven-webapp: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.infy.demos:maven-webapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.infy.demos:maven-webapp:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to deployment (http://localhost:8081/repository/sample-snap/): Not authorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\maven-demo\pom.xml to com.infy.demos/maven-webapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\maven-demo\target\maven-webapp.war to com.infy.demos/maven-webapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Already configure Nexus Repository Manager Servers in the Jenkins and tested the connection showing `Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection succeeded`. 
Using Nexus OSS 3.19.1-01.

Comment: Your issue is: `Not authorized `. How have you setup up your credentials? Is that user authorized to upload to your repo?

Comment: yes, set up the credentials in Nexus Repository Manager Servers plugin of Jenkins.

Comment: Can you verify from command line that user can authenticate and upload an atrifact, outside of Jnekins? Use mvn deploy:deploy-file.

Comment: using `mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.infy.demos -DartifactId=maven-webapp -Dversion=0.0.2-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=war -Dfile=./target/maven-webapp.war -Durl=http://localhost:8081/repository/sample-snap/`  from command line gives error

Comment: Error is   `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project maven-webapp: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.infy.demos:maven-webapp:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.infy.demos:maven-webapp:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote-repository (http://localhost:8081/repository/sample-snap/): Not authorized -> [Help 1]`. But `mvn deploy` is working, I have change the version from  0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.